# How long do I have to complete the bracer guild requests based on the terms?

Tags: legend-of-heroes-trails-in-the-sky

The Bracer guild has 3 different lengths they will be available to complete, Short Medium and Long.

How do I judge whether or not they will expire, though? There is no indication that a request is going to expire regardless of term length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remaining time for the guild requests advances with in-game time.

The in-game time advances each time you advance the main story.
The easiest way to see if the in-game time has advanced, is to check if NPCs have new dialog.

The time progression for the requests is: Long -> Medium -> Short -> Failed